# Initiate Download Request Using Other AppStore App in iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, download, app-store

I basically want to open another app to downloading an item from my app. Sample AppStore apps that I want to open is Phone Drive. Scenario would be like this, I'll load a `UIWebView` from my app and then when the user taps on a download link, I'll present the user with a `UIActionSheet` prompting him to use Phone Drive or any other apps that will download the said item from the `UIWebView`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLScheme to open another app from your app. see this [apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899) and [this link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/) to implement it.

Comment: Thanks Dilip. Checking it now.